# How to fix csrf token problem after deployment on railway of django project

Tags: django, postgresql, amazon-web-services, railway

Forbidden (403)
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

Help
Reason given for failure:

```
Origin checking failed - https//:webiste does not match any trusted origins.
```

In general, this can occur when there is a genuine Cross Site Request Forgery, or when Django’s CSRF mechanism has not been used correctly. For POST forms, you need to ensure:

Your browser is accepting cookies.
The view function passes a request to the template’s render method.
In the template, there is a {% csrf_token %} template tag inside each POST form that targets an internal URL.
If you are not using CsrfViewMiddleware, then you must use csrf_protect on any views that use the csrf_token template tag, as well as those that accept the POST data.
The form has a valid CSRF token. After logging in in another browser tab or hitting the back button after a login, you may need to reload the page with the form, because the token is rotated after a login.

I added csrf_token_origin but it didn't worked for me and currently i am using python 3.11.0

> CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['']

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue

All I had to do was to install `corsheaders` using the below command:

```bash
pip install django-cors-headers
```

Then add this to your `settings.py` file under **`MIDDLEWARE`**:

```py
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['example.com']
```